How do I get my image hover effect to work?
I'm currently making a website using css and html, and I have an image (naturally skewed 7 degrees) that I want to rotate back to 0 degrees when the cursor is hovered over it. But of all the methods I find online, none of them work.
I added an ID tag to the image, then adding a css class with that ID with a transform effect, with the pseudo class :hover but that didn't work, the image didn't do anything when hovered over it.
I'll show my code below, if anyone can provide insight.


.rotateImg {
  width: auto;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.rotateImg:hover {
  transform: rotate(-7deg);
}
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/1lAFovT.png" class="rotateImg" style="border-radius: 10px; border: 5px solid #FF8600; width: 100%; transform:rotate(7deg);">




you are  giving transform:rotate(7deg)  in inline css due to which the rules declared in class or id are ignored you can use !important tag in the :hover class and it will work like this .rotateImg:hover { transform: rotate(-7deg) !important; }
